# Call a JavaScript function from a Wordpress page?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've added the following function to my wordpress theme javascript file `wp-content/themes/xxx/js/script.js`

```
function calculateBmi() {
  var weight = document.bmiForm.weight.value
  var height = document.bmiForm.height.value
  if (weight > 0 && height > 0) {   
    var finalBmi = weight/(height/100*height/100)
    document.bmiForm.bmi.value = finalBmi
    if (finalBmi < 18.5) {
      document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "That you are too thin."
    }
    if (finalBmi > 18.5 && finalBmi < 25) {
      document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "That you are healthy."
    }
    if (finalBmi > 25) {
      document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "That you have overweight."
    }
  }
  else{
    alert("Please Fill in everything correctly")
  }
}
```

I have added the following code on a wordpress page (in admin) with a form that calls the function when you press the button

```
<form name="bmiForm">
  Your Weight(kg): <input type="text" name="weight" size="10"><br />
  Your Height(cm): <input type="text" name="height" size="10"><br />
  <input type="button" value="Calculate BMI" onClick="calculateBmi()"><br />
  Your BMI: <input type="text" name="bmi" size="10"><br />
  This Means: <input type="text" name="meaning" size="25"><br />
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

Nothing happens when I click the button and chrome console gives the following message.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: calculateBmi is not defined ?page_id=1368:126
>   onclick

What is it that is wrong?

Comment: Sounds like your JS file isn't included properly. Take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript to see how to do this the right way.

Comment: It's theme creator that created the .js-file and that person's functions works and the include looks like:  

wp_enqueue_script('custom_script',$jscriptURL.'script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

Comment: On a side note, please mind that JavaScript does not have block scopes.

Comment: @Xtreme The `function calculateBmi` may not be defined globally. See if it's embedded within another `function`. If it is, then accessing it depends on whether `script.js` exposed it to other scripts.

Comment: Created a new .js without 'jquery' (no dependencies). Works now.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of enqueuing properly. First, a test page with the HTML provided. Note the use of the global `$b5f_hook` to catch our page afterwards.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_auxiliary_menu' );

function add_auxiliary_menu() 
{
    global $b5f_hook;
    $b5f_hook = add_menu_page(
        'Test', 
        '<span style="color:#e57300;">Test</span>', 
        'edit_pages', 
        'b5f_page_id', 
        'b5f_page_callback',
        '', // icon default for empty
        1  // create before Dashboard menu item
    );
}
function b5f_page_callback()
{
    ?>
    <form name="bmiForm">
      Your Weight(kg): <input type="text" name="weight" size="10"><br />
      Your Height(cm): <input type="text" name="height" size="10"><br />
      <input type="button" value="Calculate BMI" onClick="calculateBmi()"><br />
      Your BMI: <input type="text" name="bmi" size="10"><br />
      This Means: <input type="text" name="meaning" size="25"><br />
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

Enqueuing the script, not sure why jQuery is being included as dependency, but it doesn't matter:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'b5f_enqueue' );
function b5f_enqueue( $hook )
{
    global $b5f_hook;
    if( $hook !== $b5f_hook ) # Not our page, bail out
        return;

    $jscriptURL = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js';
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_script', $jscriptURL, array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
}
```

And the script file contains the JS code provided:

```
function calculateBmi() { /* rest of the code */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

your function is not defined because it contains syntax errors.
Add ";" after each line and check for other errors e.g. using [jslint tool](http://www.jslint.com/)